# iAd banner on iPhone 6 wrong size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Ok so I'm upgrading my iOS app to take advantage of the iPhone 6's larger display but iAd is still showing ads of the iPhone 5s dimensions (both on the banner and when you select the advert).

There's an annoying blank space either side of the banner, and a full frame of blank space around the view when the advert is selected.

My app has a correct iPhone 6 launch image and is showing native resolution (no scaling). Grateful if anyone can give me a pointer as to where I am going wrong.

The iAd frame is configured and sized with this code and placed at the bottom of the screen:

```
[_UIiAd setFrame:(CGRectMake(0, screenHeight - 100, screenWidth, 50))];
```

It looks like this:

[image: iAd Banner]

Comment: Can anyone confirm the size of the actual banner on the iphone 6 and 6 plus?  Is it still 50 points high?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that iAd is actually working fine, but Apple has not yet modified the dimensions of the test ad to suit the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.

*Update 25th Nov 2014* - Apple has now updated iAd banners to display the correct dimensions.

Comment: My ad is left aligned to rect is there any issue in my frame??

Comment: Is that update a quote, from where? Do iAd banners display full size width in iPhone 6/Plus as of now?